# .htaccess rewriterule is going in a infinity loop

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

in a domain, I have a .htaccess that is configured like this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^admin$ /admin/ [R,L]

RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/sf2/sub/%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING}&id=7 [P]
```

in the old server, this is working very well, but in the new server, the rule is going in a loop and it's impossible to come in the website.

When I open the page, I have this error :

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /sf2/sub/sf2/sub/sf2/sub/......./sf2/sub/sub.php
```

As you can see, the rule is calling infinity time !!! and I want only one time. I know that this is nothing to do with .htaccess because this is working well in other server that call the same file.

may be this is apache configuration ? I don't know.

If someone has already has this trouble ? How to fixe it ?

I transfer all file from old server (which is working well) to new one (which is not working now)

What I need is : a domain (num 1) is redirected to an other domain (num 2) with the URL of the num 1 and adding a id parameter and after showed the website with the files of num 2 called

Comment: This _obviously_ leads to an infinite rewriting loop, why should it not? Look at the second ruile: you _always_ rewrite _unconditionally_, regardless of what actually is requested. Why should it stop to rewrite? This assumes that www.example.com stands for the actual host this rule is implemented in, since you did not tell otherwise. Also the `P` flag is surprising...

Comment: But why the same configuration is working on other server? What should I write for what I want? The P flag keep the url of the first domain in the link

Comment: Maybe mod_proxy isn't configured properly, or different than in the old server.

Comment: But this is working in all other server that has the same .htaccess.. this is not working only for domain that are in the same server....

Comment: How can I check the mod_proxy configuration ?